# how use git hook run msbuild.exe

Tags: git, msbuild, githooks

how use git hook run msbuild

I want use git hook script run msbuild files

```
`#!/bin/bash
echo "Script started"
git --work-tree=/c/inetpub/wwwroot/A_BACK --git-dir=/c/inetpub/wwwroot/Bonobo.Git.Server/App_Data/Repositories/A checkout -f
echo "Script ended" `
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "STEP 1 Script started"
git --work-tree=/D/pro/xmgl/syxmgl --git- 
dir=/d/pro/Bonobo.Git.Server/App_Data/Repositories/Project_SY checkout -f
echo "STEP 1 Script ended"

#build
echo "STEP 2 building"
/C/Windows/Microsoft.Net/Framework/v4.0.30319/msbuild.exe 
/D/pro/xmgl/syxmgl/project.sln  //p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
echo "STEP 2 builded"
```